# GCM is not working on Android Virtual Device: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

is throwing exception while calling

```
    try {
        GCMIntentService.register(this.getContext());
        //isRegistationPending = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //probleme during GCM registration
        SnooziUtility.trace(TRACETYPE.ERROR, "GCM Registration error :  " +  e.toString());
    }
```

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf

is it because GCM is not supported on Virtual Device?

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this question got down voted? I find it outrages that some a-holes on this site just do everything possible to keep newbs getting more reputations. The least the can do is to justify the down vote instead of hiding behind anonymity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `com.google.android.gsf` package to your project and use it wherever you need it.

Comment: I suppose the reason why it does not throw me this exception while testing on real device is because this package is already installed on a real device?

Comment: Probably yes, however, as the developer of your project you cannot rely on some packages being installed by default.